# TLS definition in libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS definition

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake

I am getting below error while building my project, I am using ghs math libraries.

```
errno: TLS definition in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS
definition in ../../../../dc_tools/libs/ghs_math_lib/libghs_math.so section .bss
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

I have tried including `errno.h` header file as suggested by some answers to similar problem but that didn't work.

Here are flags

```
C_FLAGS =  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Werror

C_DEFINES = -DCRASH_ON_ASSERTION -DDC_ASSERT_LOG=\"/home/d65ef124-f0a8-4f0f-85b5-7c0f7ec4b49a/pj-dc_int/assertions.log\" -DLINUX -DTARGET_GCCx86 -DTARGET_SELENA -DVFC_USER_CONFIG=\"/home/d65ef124-f0a8-4f0f-85b5-7c0f7ec4b49a/pj-dc_int/dc_tools/vfc_config/dc_vfc_user_cfg_ghs.hpp\" -D_Bool=bool -D__linux -Dghs_math_EXPORTS

C_INCLUDES = -I/home/d65ef124-f0a8-4f0f-85b5-7c0f7ec4b49a/pj-dc_int/dc_tools/selena/inc/common -I/home/d65ef124-f0a8-4f0f-85b5-7c0f7ec4b49a/pj-dc_int/dc_tools/libs/ghs_math_lib/inc -I/home/d65ef124-f0a8-4f0f-85b5-7c0f7ec4b49a/pj-dc_int/dc_tools/libs/ghs_math_lib/src
```

Comment: Hello,  show your makefile, please

Comment: It sounds like different compiler or linker option are being used for different components. It looks like `libc.so.6` and `libghs_math.so` are conflicting. What options does `libghs_math.so` manual state to use to compile a program? It may be as simple as deleting `extern int errno;` and including `<errno.h>`. Also see [errno: TLS definition in /lib64/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/errno-tls-definition-in-lib64-libc-so-6-section-tbss-mismatches-non-tls-reference-528681/). Ping @FlorianWeimer.

Comment: Try `# apt-get install libc6-dev`

Comment: @Rahul: As you can see, comments are not suited for multile code snippets. Actually, on Stack Overflow we expect the **question post** itself to contain all required information. Comments are temporary things: their intention is to request the asker for more info, but that info should be added into the question post itself, not as a comment. Please, [edit] your question and add information from your comment into it.

Answer (score 0):

your question: tls definition in libc mismatches non-tls reference
---- you may search regexp "extern .+ errno", and maybe you will find that the project did already reference a non-TLS(thread local storage) version of errno.